# WordPress single IP allow wp-admin access

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

In WordPress my network team restrict wpadmin folder with single ip. So my admin-ajax.php ajax call are 403 forbidden for end user. Is there a solution to allow everyone to access this?

- Step 1: restrict Wp-admin folder file wise, and allow admin-ajax file
- Step 2: Any another method is available to ajax call without adamin-ajax file

Are any of these possible?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow access folder by ip, then please add the below code in `.htaccess` file.

```
<Directory /path/to/the/folder>
            Options +Indexes
            IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from X.X.X.X
</Directory>
```

**For specific File then add the below code**

```
<Files file-name.php>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from X.X.X.X
 </Files>
```